# nVidia nForce and GeForce drivers colliding

Tags: drivers, windows-vista, nvidia-geforce, nvidia-nforce

My system has 2 nVidia graphics cards.  A PCIe 9400GT, and an 8200 built-in (nForce 730a).  I decided to upgrade my drivers to 285.62, as it says it supports both the 8 and 9 series GPUs.

After it installed, and a reboot, I got a BSoD (nvlddmkm.sys).  So I went to Safe Mode, and uninstalled the drivers, and then removed the video cards from Windows' Device Manager.

I rebooted, and went Safe Mode, installed the drivers, then rebooted back to Safe Mode (a trick I found a forum somewhere).

In Device Manager, it said my 8200 wasn't using resources because it had a problem (resources tab on device properties in Device Manager); when I checked the resources for the 9800GT, it had actual data.

I disabled my built-in 8200, and Windows booted up correctly.  I'm afraid to re-enable it because it'll probably BSoD when it reboots.

Anyone have any advice for getting a built-in nVidia card (nForce) and a GeForce nVidia card to work together with the same driver (285.62)?

P.S. The previous drivers I had were 197.13 (from the nForce 15.56 package).

Note: I'm running Windows Vista 32-bit.

Comment: Oh man I went through hell with a 6400gs and 8800GT in a similar setup... I never did get it to work (properly) with both, but I do remember it performing better when I: 1. removed the add in card 2. Installed drivers for the built in GPU 3. replaced add in card and disabled built in 4. installed drivers for add in card 5. Re-enable built in GPU.

Comment: @Kyle: That's a good idea.  Only problem is, which drives do I install for the built-in?  The nForce's graphics drivers (197.13) or the latest (285.62)?

Comment: I would say start with the latest and work your way back if they don't work properly after enabling everything. Best of luck, feel free to leave me a @comment if you need any further advice.

Comment: @Kyle: I currently have 285.62 installed.  I have the built-in card disabled, and the 9400GT is working fine.

Comment: @Kyle: I just tried that, and BAM!  It Worked!  Thanks a lot dude! :-D  Now I can have 4 monitors (if I can get 2 more from my boss :-P)!!

Comment: That's awesome, glad I could help. I'm going to move to an answer so others can find this easily.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Steps to try:

1. Removed the add in card.
2. Install drivers for the built in GPU.
3. replaced add in card and disabled built in.
4. Install drivers for add in card.
5. Re-enable built in GPU

I also suggest starting with the latest drivers and working your way backwards to find one that works.

Comment: I did it in a slightly different order, but still seemed to work.  1) Disable built-in, 2) Install drivers for add in, 3) Enable built-in, 4) Windows BSoDs, 5) Remove Add-on Card, 6) Install drivers for built-in, 7) Re-install add-on

Answer (score 0):

This is not a supported configuration (video cards from different families) on Vista. It is on Windows 7. This is due to limitations in Windows itself, not in the video card drivers. If it does work, it's basically by luck.

Comment: It was working before.  Before I decided to upgrade to the latest drivers.